# How to create animation in python kivy(change frames per second)

Tags: python, kivy

I want to create animation in python kivy(changing source of image), but I can't do it. I tried to use Clock scheduling to change source of Image per 0.01 seconds, but it's too slowly and looks not smoothly. What i should do to fix it?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>
    FloatLayout:
        id: layout
        Image:
            id: background
            size: self.size
            nocache: True
            source: 'background.gif'
        Button:
            id: change_background
            pos:(380, 130)
            on_release: root.change()
            background_normal: 'button.gif'
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size:(60, 60)
''')
class RootWidget(FloatLayout, ModalView):
    def change(self):
        self.num = 0
        self.an = ['an1.gif', 'an2.gif', 'an3.gif']
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.animation, 0.01)

    def animation(self, dt):
        if self.num != 3:
            self.ids.background.source = self.an[self.num]
            self.num += 1
        else:
            self.ids.background.source = 'an4.gif'

class AnimApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnimApp.run()
```

Comment: You won't achieve greater than 60fps this way, at least without adjusting some settings, as that's what kivy targets by default. Maybe the lack of smoothness you've seen arises from that.

Comment: how to fix it??

Comment: Try setting your interval to something more reasonable, like `1.0/30.0`.